# Drawing faces are forbidden, but I would like to know if I can draw parts of Human body?

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

Assalaamu 'alaikum warehmatullahi wabarkatuhu,

I have a question deriving in many small queries that I am doubtful of. I am well aware of the hadiths that Our beloved Prophet quoted about prohibiting drawing of faces and blotting of them. I strictly follow it and don't draw faces but If you can answer the following it will help me greatly so that I may not do it and tell others about it.

**Can I draw:**

1) Body parts like only hands, feet upperbody, chin etc.

2) Silhouettes/shadows.

3) Only eyes, or nose, ears.

4) Backside of a Persons body.

5) Only hair. And as I draw on digital basis

6) Edit an existing face? Like just drawing eyes or correcting an angle of face.

7) Editing the existing drawing(face) by copying and pasting eyes or mouth if not drawing etc to a picture.

8) Generating face by premade options in a program.

9) Modifying a face/picture e.g.:- drawing more into the portrait like making it       scarier or old etc.

A simple reply as yes or no is answerable but it would be better if explained in detail, thank you so much Jazakallahu khair

Comment: I'd like to mention that your inquiry would be helpful and constructive for the site, since it is counted as FAQ. Good luck mate.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: uh-huh, dear mate, I meant you asked a question which is the question of many people, that's why your question(by the answers) can be helpful.             و من الله توفیق

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shirk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_(Islam)) is the:

> sin of practising idolatry or polytheism

That is setting up partners to Allah.

This does not have to take material form, but it may; it's for this reason that in Islam the human form is generally not represented; or *other* forms; for example in sura [Al-R'af - the Heights: 7.148](http://corpus.quran.com/concept.jsp?id=golden-calf):

> The people of Moses made, in his absence, out of their ornaments the image of a calf. It seemed to low. Did they not see that it could not speak, not guide them on the way. They took it for worship and they did wrong.

Intention matters. Images, drawings used otherwise are not *shirk*; but given this ancient connection certain prohibitions remain; in particular representing prophets by images.

One particular Hadith in Bukhari shows the Prophet castigating those who set up images in the Ka'ba.

Drawing pictures to represent the human form is possible; for example one sees medical students learning human anatomy from exactly this; we also see parents taking photographs of their children.

Comment: In conclusion I can draw their parts or forms upon intention but not faces correct?? And by parts I mean every part ofcourse not in an inappropriate manner. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
                                   IN THE NAME OF ALLAH
```

> Drawing faces is haram and forbidden, but I would like to know if
>   I can draw parts?

On the whole, “drawing the face is not impermissible”,“but making sculpture of human and animal completely is not permissible based on Mashhood… Wallaho A’lamo (And God knows best).

Consequently, probably, drawing the parts which you named can be permissible. Note: the mentioned quotation is according to Ayatollah Khamenei as a scholar of Shi'a.

---

**Reference**:

[portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/2828#gsc.tab=0)