# Is art (of faces, eyes, etc.) halal in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, jinn, malaikah, image, art

I'm a Muslim, and I specifically like to draw as a hobby now and then. Recently, I read several comments and things here and there on the Internet saying that drawing faces or things with souls (like people, animals) is haram because Angels do not enter the vicinity when the art in question is present, and you will be Punished on the Day, asked to make the art brought to life, which we all know only Allah SWT can do.

By my upbringing, as long as we overturn anything with a face so it doesn't show, it's alright, and I've only heard about Jinn being attracted to rooms with pictures of faces and the like, but never that Angels don't enter.

What I would like to know, is, is it considered halal for me to make art of faces, people, eyes, animals, creations with souls, etc.?

Comment: You should first search a bit:
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam?rq=1 
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27863/drawing-faces-are-forbidden-but-i-would-like-to-know-if-i-can-draw-parts-of-hum?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As-salaamu 'alaykum, wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

.. ..

According to the research that I have done, drawing the things that you mentioned (e.g. faces, eyes, or anything with a soul) is generally haraam.

.. ..

An exception seems to be made in the case of children; if you search this topic on the website www.islamqa.info/en, then I think that you will find the scholars saying that it is permissible to draw these things, and even to make toys, for children, as that is a way for them to learn about animals.