# is it allowed to draw a face with only eyes?

Tags: drawing

Assalamualaikum,
I've been drawing for almost 3 years and recently I read somewhere that drawing humans isn't allowed.
But I wanted to know if I draw a face with only eyes and I don't draw the nose or mouth,would it be haram?
You can answer with a simple yes or no if you'd like ^^

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79kc2bvwwIY

Comment: Also: [Is art (of faces, eyes, etc.) halal in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32893/17163).